# How to install the DXA 2.1 Model Service extension

Tags: dxa, installation, model-service, dxa-2.1

I'm currently installing DXA 2.1 in a Sites 9 environment.
We are trying to install the new Model Service extension (an extension to the Content Microservice), but the documentation isn't very clear on where to add the extension parameter (https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v11/GUID-40677184-F773-4A39-889E-2154DD3A7446)

> Modify your Content Service (or Session-enabled Content Service) configuration to add the following startup parameter:
>   Add the following environment variable:
>
> --plugin=PATH/udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-xxxx-core.zip
>
> Where PATH specifies the location from step 1 and stated as relative to the bin/ folder. The path separators should work on both Unix and Windows.
>
> For example: --plugin=../extensions/udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-xxxx-core.zip

I'm not really sure where this --plugin=... should go. I tried adding it to the arguments of my installservice.ps script, but that didn't work.

**UPDATE**

I added the plugin=... line in my installservice.ps1 script on the jvmoptions. This allowed me to install the service, but when I want to start the service, i get the error "the system cannot open the file" in the event log.

I double checked my zip file was there, and i also made sure the zip file was unblocked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Indeed! documentation is bit unclear, an example command not work for windows, I did manage to install successfully, I have sent the message to fix the documentation, I will leave the comment in the documentation.

Try the following steps to fix the installation of DXA Model Extension:

**Option1:**

1. Create the **extensions** folder in content service root.
2. Copy the \dxa\cis\dxa-model-service-extension\udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip file to **extensions** folder
3. UnInstall the Tridion SessionContent Service
4. Re-install the service by this below command:

> .\installService.ps1 -auto-register
>   --plugin=./extensions/udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip

**Option2:**

1. Create the **extensions** folder in content service root.
2. Copy the \dxa\cis\dxa-model-service-extension\udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip file to **extensions** folder
3. Create the Environment variable **PLUGIN**
   Place the value as **./extensions/udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip**
4. Restart the system
5. UnInstall the Tridion SessionContent Service
6. ReInstall the service by .\installService.ps1 - not required to pass **--plugin=./** in the startup parameter

You can verify this successfully installed or not by looking at the content service plugins folder should have **udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core** folder and **udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1047-core.zip** file.

[image]

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I tried the first option and this works. After the install, I can see a plugins folder with the zip file and unzipped files

Comment: The problem is that the documentation incorrectly states that the location is relative to the bin folder, so ../extensions... instead of ./extensions

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that you can add these parameters to either the start or the installService scripts, with the caveat that if you add it when calling installService you will need to first uninstall the service for it to take effect.