# How to setup DXA 2.2 (NET) WebApp Core solution

Tags: dxa, sites-9, dxa2.2, dxa-dotnet

Can you explain the steps to create a Visual Studio solution for the Example DXA Core website.

It should contain projects:

- **DxaWebApp**
  https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/tree/release/2.2/ 2.2.6_Hotfix
- **Sdl.Web.Modules.Core**
  https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-net/Core

Purpose explore with debugger.

What I did:

- added above repo's to my solution, changed web.config (discovery url and secret).

"Failed with load configuration file: ..\Site\bin\config\cd_ambient_conf.xml".

What should here content of this file. Empty? It's better to have steps for best practice of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DXA 2.2 .NET + Core and Search Module Solution build/configuration

1. Download the following OOTB sources and modules from GitHub:
   https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/tree/release/2.2
   https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/release/2.2
2. Extract both sources zip and Go to **dxa-modules-release-2.2\webapp-net** this folder and copy **Core** and **Search** folder modules and also **DxaModulesCommon.Props** file
3. Go to **dxa-web-application-dotnet-release-2.2** folder and paste those folders and **DxaModulesCommon.Props** file here
4. Open the **DxaFramework.sln** and click ok to ignore the unsupported Sdl.Web.Documentation project error message
5. Right-click **DxaFramework** solution to add the following existing projects

- Core\Sdl.Web.Modules.Core.csproj
- Search\Sdl.Web.Modules.Search.csproj
- Search\SI4T.Query.CloudSearch\SI4T.Query.CloudSearch.csproj

6. Go to **Sdl.Web.Site** project references and then right-click and add reference and then click left side Projects and select the following projects

- Sdl.Web.Modules.Core
- Sdl.Web.Modules.Search
- SI4T.Query.CloudSearch

7. Right-click **Sdl.Web.Modules.Core** project and build
8. Once successful build – expand the **Sdl.Web.Modules.Core** project and copy the Areas folder and go to **Sdl.Web.Site** project paste it in the root folder.
9. Right-click Sdl.Web.Modules.Search project and build
10. Once successful build – expand the Sdl.Web.Modules.Search project and copy the Areas folder and go to **Sdl.Web.Site** project pastes it in the root folder.
11. Go to S**DL.Web.Site** and open **web.config** update the following configs sections

```
 In the appSettings section Update the **Web.config** to change the default module to Core 
 <add key="default-module" value="Core" /> 
 Also update the following configs to as per your cusotomer environment.    
 <add key="discovery-service-uri" value="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc"/> 
 <add key="oauth-client-secret" value="xxxx" />
```

12. Update the existing Unity Configuration type as follows, It's applicable only to sites 9.0+

```
<type type="ILocalizationResolver" mapTo="GraphQLLocalizationResolver">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>      
<type type="IModelServiceProvider" mapTo="GraphQLModelServiceProvider">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>          
<type type="IContentProvider" mapTo="GraphQLContentProvider">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>
<type type="ILinkResolver" mapTo="GraphQLLinkResolver">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>
<type type="IBinaryProvider" mapTo="GraphQLBinaryProvider">
  <lifetime type="singleton" />
</type>
```

13. Copy **cd_ambient_conf.xml** config to keep in the website bin\config folder (File can be copied from SDL Tridion Sites Installation Media **\Content Delivery\roles\api\rest\dotnet\config\cd_ambient_conf.xml**)
14. Installing the Search module in the web application
    Open **Unity.config** to update to add the following config sections
    Add UnityDeclaration:

```
<assembly name="Sdl.Web.Modules.Search" /> 
<namespace name="Sdl.Web.Modules.Search.Providers" />

Set UnityTypeMapping:
<type type="ISearchProvider" mapTo="IQSearchProvider" />

Update web.config to add elastic index name
<add key="iq-search-index" value="udp-index" />
```

Note:
In order to use GraphQLContentProvider, mandatory to Install the DXA Model Extension for Model support – Tridion Sites 9.0+

Install the DXA Model Extension in Content Service, Download the [DXA model extension file](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/releases/download/DXA_2.2/SDL.DXA.NET.2.2.zip)
and extract from **\SDL DXA .NET 2.2\cis\udp-content-dxa-extension\udp-content-dxa-extension-assembly-11.0.0-1077-core.zip**

[How to install the DXA Model Service extension](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/19591/how-to-install-the-dxa-2-1-model-service-extension/19595#19595)

I hope it helps

Comment: Example works!  Thanks. I did'nt install step 14. if needed we can do it later. It all runs on .NET 4.6.2. We use sites 9 and .NET 47.2 is advised [here](https://docs.sdl.com/755209/705922/sdl-tridion-sites-9-prerequisites/content-manager-java-and--net-support-history). What is your advise about .NET version for deploy for a new webapplication ?

Comment: Good to know it helped, the link you have provided Content Manager prerequisites .NET version, The DXA Framework built against .NET 4.6.2, but you can use them in a .NET 4.7.2 (or even 4.8) Web App too. please accept the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

This issue is faced by other people including me while setting up DXA web application. Details on how to fix this issue can be found at https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/issues/33 . Please check that , I hope it would resolve the issue.

Comment: It's placed on "DXA 1.6 Retired"? The documentation is now not a quick start for my approach. Maybe it can be improved here SDL DXA > SDL Digital Experience Accelerator 2.2 > DXA module reference > DXA Core module